# ASP .NET application is trying to use local paths to open a file when I have changed the code to use HTTP paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am developing an ASP.NET application and have been testing it on my local machine using Visual Studio. While I was testing it there, I was using local filepaths because my program needs to write and read from these files. When I dragged and dropped my files into my website folder to test on network, I changed the filepaths to be network filepaths instead of local ones. However, when I try to access these files, my program throws an error that it cannot find the filepath, and prints my local filepath from when I was testing it on my machine. Here is the error message it throws, I've censored the local paths, but they are the same local paths on my machine as when I was testing locally.
[Error message when trying to write to Credentials.xml, which is hosted on the web server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r63wZ.png)

Here is the function that attempts to open the file.

```
protected void createAccBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = createUserIn.Value;
            string password = createPassIn.Value;
            XDocument doc;
            doc = XDocument.Load(@"https://myurl.com/Credentials.xml");
            var element = new XElement("User", new XElement("Username", username), new XElement("Password", password));
            doc.Root.Add(element);
            TestBox.InnerText = doc.ToString();
            doc.Save(@"https://myurl.com/page0/Credentials.xml");

            
        }
```

I used the VS "ASP.NET Web Application in C#" template in order to set this up. I assume that somewhere in the files there is just a saved reference to my local files it keeps trying to use but I have no idea where that would be. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried clean and rebuild solution in VS and recopying, which didn't work. I've also looked through many config files but couldn't find any reference anywhere to the local file. That filepath is not written anywhere in my code, so it must have saved from when I was working local

Comment: *When I dragged and dropped my files into my website folder to test on network, I changed the filepaths to be network filepaths instead of local ones* How exactly? The paths appear to be hardcoded.

Comment: The code for the function I provided used to have local filepaths within the parameters of XDocument.Load(). I changed them to reference where they would be within my web server

Comment: What do you expect to happen an a `Save` call passing in a HTTP(S) URI? The argument should be a file name https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save?view=net-7.0#system-xml-linq-xdocument-save(system-string).

Comment: If you want to load files from the web, you're going to have to use something like HttpClient to request the file content and pass the stream to `XDocument.Load` assuming there's an overload that takes a stream.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but when you say you copied the files, did you copy just the .aspx files, or did you copy the contents of the `bin` folder as well?

Comment: Not a stupid question. I copied everything including the bin folder. I assume thats the root of my problems but I dont know what part of that to change to get it to work

Comment: Regardless of if the way I'm doing it is correct in order to access the file, it doesn't change the fact that the program is still trying to reference a file that isnt even on the server, and is a local filepath, which is all I'm really trying to fix for now

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense, does it? I would double check a couple things: make sure your traffic is in fact being handled by the machine you think it is (i.e. check W3C logs), check the timestamps on your binaries to make sure they are changing when you deploy (could be that a file is locked), also reset iis to ensure caches are cleared. You might consider completely deleting the IIS application and recreating from scratch with the new build. Unfortunately I don't see any obvious smoking gun here.

Comment: Try using Server.MapPath to get the physical file path on the server instead of hardcoding the file path.

Answer (score 0):

First up, I would create some folder in/on/for your web project; say, MyXmlDocs.

Often, how path names are resolved for web sites can be confusing.

So, in your example, we assume (even on your dev computer, working local), you created (use add from Visual Studio) that folder.

So, of course right click in project explore, choose add, then choose add folder.

For example, this:

[image]

And add our folder called MyXmlDocs.

So, you now have this:

[image]

OK, so now we need a few concepts as to how this works:

Web based URLs:

A web based URL will be the base root web site name, then folder, then document.

So this:

```
 http://www.mysite/MyXmlDocs/Credentials.xml
```

or maybe (during local development)

```
 http://localhost:63267/MyXmlDocs/Credentials.xml
```

However, note that code behind never uses a web based URL, but will always use a regular Windows file name. And that includes the FULL PATH name of the file.

So,

Web-based URLs - from web site = site/Folder/File

But, code behind: the total path name - like ANY regular Windows file name!

(And internal, now how files and folders use "\" (backslash).

So, how does C# work with files? It doesn't matter if you're doing web development, or desktop, or whatever. That code behind still works like it always did in the past, and that includes correct Windows file names. So, C#/vb.net code when dealing with file names will require you to use a valid windows file name (and path).

So, it is thus obvious that while the web server (IIS - internet services) will mate the web site + folder(s) + file name for you, this ONLY applies when using a web based URL to a file name in a folder.

But, such path names are of ZERO use in code behind. Remember that above rule:

VB.net, or C# code to read and use files will still be regular windows code, and thus you need a legal Windows file name, NOT a web based file, and not a web based URL to read/open/use/enjoy when using code behind.

So, this means we need to convert those "supposed" web URLs to a full file name in code. The method you use is Server.MapPath.

Let's run this code.

Markup:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            Text="Show path names"
            OnClick="Button1_Click"
            />

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
            Text="">
        </asp:Label>
```

Code for button:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // show path name to MyExmlDocs/Credentials.xml

        string sFile = Server.MapPath("~/MyXmlDocs/Credentials.xml");

        Label1.Text = sFile;

        //XDocument doc;
        //doc = XDocument.Load(sFile);

    }
```

Result:

[image]

So, as you can see, you really don't care where the web site runs from, we simple take the URL, or what would be the external URL, and use Server.MapPath, and this will convert web based URL's to "internal" full legal windows file and path.

So, internal code (code behind) will always use correct and legal Windows path names.

Web-based URLs are from the sites roots. So, code behind does NOT work like web based URLs, and you have to keep the 2 concepts 100% separate in your mind.

Always ask: is this code behind running, or is this a web based URL?

The web site, IIS web services, and even typing in a legal path name to a folder in the site always starts at the base site name.

However, for code behind, that is still always a regular Windows legal file name.